# How to expose AWS S3 data on a website in proper directory structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I have some experiment data which I keep on Amazon S3 as well as EC2. I expose the data I keep on EC2 on a website using nginx server. We get new experiment data every hour.

Here is how it looks like: http://uploads.projectbismark.net/

Now, I want to avoid keeping a copy of the data on EC2. And directly link people to the S3 data. But, I want the website to look somewhat like it is now.

What is the best way to do that? 
Currently, I am thinking of writing a script which gets the directory structure of the S3 using AWS CLI and then writes a static html file with links to the S3 data files. 
Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: try Nginx S3 Proxy for that https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog